# Is it possible to directly access a position (not a key) in a multimap

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

**Question:** How do you access a value at a specified position in a key range without loops?

The only possible way I know to acquire this data is by incrementing the iterator however many times the position is from the beginning or end of a key range.

***edit*** The reason I am reluctant in using loops is to reduce processing time by getting the wanted value when the values position in an index is known.

Comment: Use a different container.

Comment: Basically go back to vectors? I thought so.

Comment: Doesn't e.g. `std::advance(iterator, 5)` work to get the fifth item?

Comment: @RogerRowland: how is `advance` different from "incrementing the iterator hoever many times", in this context?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OP asked how to do it without loops.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the equivalent of using a loop? I read the definition  saying it did. `Otherwise, the function uses repeatedly the increase or decrease operator`

Comment: Well, yes, just a suggestion - not entirely sure what your problem really is though...

Comment: @RogerRowland: the answer to "without loops" is not "put the loop in a function, call the function"

Comment: If the OP's sole interest is in eliminating the loop *syntax*, then `advance` is fine. If he wants constant-complexity instead of linear complexity, it provides no improvement.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I literally meant no looping in any way shape or form. Not just the syntax, hence `directly access a position`.

Comment: Is it merely the key comparisions (log time) you want to get rid of, or is it important that the item be the n'th one in the map's order? In the former case you may just use a pointer (not sure about if it can be invalidated as long as the item's there, check it out), or the unordered map, i.e. a hash table. In the latter case, use a different container.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: In that case, Alf is exactly correct: you need a different data structure.

Comment: @JerryCoffin actually, I believe that may be something i'm interested in. I'll try it.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: a vector will let you do it with constant complexity. Another choice is a binary tree in which each node stores the number of nodes in its left subtree, which can do it in logarithmic time. The tree also supports logarithmic insertion/deletion, which are linear in a sorted vector.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf can you provide an answer, or just a comment describing what you mean by pointer? Reason I ask is because I do not understand where the pointer should be pointing to. The iterator? Is the pointer the iterator( no )? Or the actual multi map?

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: I meant, given an iterator `it` you can just keep the pointer you get from `&*it`. But this only helps for *one* element. You can iterate over the map and store pointers to all items, in a vector. But this collection needs to be updated as soon as changes are made to the map. The upshot is that it all sounds pretty **problem-specific**, and the (real) problem is unspecified... The only known fact is that direct use of a general `map` is inappropriate. As a general solution I'd therefore go for my first comment, "use a different container".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As properly stated in the comments, you basically cannot do this on `multimap`. Or on `map`. Or on any container that does not support random access. The simple answer to the question "Why I cannot do this?" is "Because it is not in the interface".

The longer answer requires a minimal understanding of the implementation of different containers. Elements of, say, `vector` are stored in the memory consequently. Knowing address of the `i`-th element, you can add `k` and acquire the address of `i+k`-th element.

Maps (and multimaps) are different. To allow an efficient way of associative access they use some kind of trees as an underlying data structure. The simplest is the binary search tree. And all nodes of the tree are allocated in the heap. You don't know where before you actually access them. But you can access a node only through other nodes.

What you can do is to go through all elements and store their addresses in a vector, so they can now be accessed "randomly". However, this vector is invalidated once a new element is added or an element is removed from the map. There is no magic data structure which allows you both effective associative and random access.

Comment: I like the depth this answer goes to explain why maps wont work and how they do work. Thank you.